# Paging a GridView without Refreshing a Page

Tags: paging

I have a gridview with many pages, whenever i am clicking another page number the whole page is refreshing, but i don't want that, i want only the particular to be refreshed.

Below is my code,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateExpences" UpdateMode="Conditional"runat="server">  
<contenttemplate> 
</contenttemplate>
</asp:Updatepanel>
```

Inside updatepanel I have written my gridview.
   so, My question is what changes do i need to change in my code?

Comment: Where is the GridView in your code? How are you handling the index changes? is AllowPaging enabled? Are you using collections or a database?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="grd1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"EnableViewState="false"AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10"                                                                               
OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" OnRowCancelingEdit="*_RowCancelingEdit"OnRowEditing="*_RowEditing"OnRowUpdating="*_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="*_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="*_RowDataBound"EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true">

Comment: Rather than using a GridView, you might consider simply an HTML table and then use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) calls to a [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) to accomplish your paging and other interaction needs. The results should have better client and server performance and be easier to modify.

Answer (score 0):

`EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true"` There is your problem right there.

Quoting from the MSDN [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295545.aspx) control article:

> The following ASP.NET controls are not compatible with partial-page
>   updates, and are therefore not designed to work inside an UpdatePanel
>   control:
>
> - Treeview control under several conditions. One is when callbacks are    enabled that are not part of an asynchronous postback. Another
>     is    when you set styles directly as control properties instead of
>     implicitly styling the control by using a reference to CSS styles.
>     Another is when the EnableClientScript property is false (the default 
>     is true). Another is if you change the value of the
>     EnableClientScript property between asynchronous postbacks.
> - Menu control when you set styles directly as control properties    instead of implicitly styling the control by using a reference to CSS 
>     styles.
> - FileUpload and HtmlInputFile controls when they are used to upload    files as part of an asynchronous postback.
> - **GridView and DetailsView controls when their    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks property is set to true. The default is false.**
> - Login, PasswordRecovery, ChangePassword, and CreateUserWizard    controls whose contents have not been converted to editable
>     templates.
> - The Substitution control.